# QFileInfo file access penalty

Tags: qt, qfileinfo

Accroding to the `QFileInfo` documentation:

> Some of `QFileInfo`'s functions query the file system, but for performance reasons, some functions only operate on the file name itself.

However, I'm still not sure **which methods do access the file itself under the hood and which don't**. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    QFileInfo fi("path/to/my/file");
    qDebug() << fi.fileName();
}
```

Does this code has penalty over the following?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    QString fileName = QString("path/to/my/file").split('/').last();
    qDebug() << fileName;
}
```

Because I'm not sure **which `QFileInfo` methods (or even constructor) access the file itself**.

Of course, I can do some profiling, and probably it would be a premature optimization in terms of the code speed, however I'm worried about the HDD. I know about the `QFileInfo` caching, so imagine that I will try to get the filename of different files.

Comment: it means "penalty" of requesting the file system (like `QFile::exists()`). Methods like `suffix()` or such have no need in such requests and they operate on paths instead.

Comment: Your second case definitely does not access OS, because you are just declaring a *string* that has nothing to do with File system.

Comment: @MohammadKanan I'm asking about the `QFileInfo` methods. The second example is just a manual way to **not** access the file system.

Comment: @AndreiR. Thank you. And what about the constructor? Tried to find the source code without luck.

Comment: The best way to know without guessing is reading the source code: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfileinfo.cpp.html .

Comment: @vahancho Thanks, found there everthing I need: constructor does **not** access the file system, as well as `fileName()`, `suffix()` and similar methods as mentioned by @AndreiR.